# Having issues with methods

Tags: java, oop, methods, constructor

Alright, I have a class assignment to create 3 predetermined methods for a rock, paper, scissors program written by the teacher. However, when I run the program it running the methods multiple times in a row. I've looked through the code several times and can't figure out the problem.

Below is the teacher provided portion of the program:

```
public class Game
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        RockPaperScissors rps = new RockPaperScissors ();  //***Your class

        int numGames = 0;
        String userChoice = "";
        String cpuChoice = "";
        String winner = "";
        int userWins = 0;
        int cpuWins = 0;


        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n");

        //Get odd number of games
        System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play?");
        numGames = in.nextInt();

        while (numGames % 2 == 0) //Even number
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, number of games must be odd.  Please try again:");
            numGames = in.nextInt();
        }

        //Flush the buffer
        in.nextLine();

        //Play the game for the number of rounds the user entered
        for (int i = 1; i <= numGames; i++)
        {
            //Get the user and computer choices
            userChoice = rps.getUserChoice();  //***Your method
            cpuChoice = rps.getCPUChoice();   //***Your method


            System.out.println("Computer chooses " + cpuChoice);

            //Pick winner
            winner = rps.pickWinner(userChoice, cpuChoice);  //***Your method


            if (winner.equalsIgnoreCase("Tie"))
            {
                System.out.println("It's a tie!  Play again.");
                numGames++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (winner.equalsIgnoreCase("User"))
                {
                    userWins++;
                }
                else if (winner.equalsIgnoreCase("Computer"))
                {
                    cpuWins++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Error in picking winner");
                }

                System.out.println(winner + " wins!");
            }

        } //end for

        //Print results
        System.out.println("\nUser wins: " + userWins);
        System.out.println("Computer wins: " + cpuWins);

        if (userWins > cpuWins)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThe user won!");
        }
        if (cpuWins > userWins)
        {
            System.out.println("The computer won!");
        }

        //Close game
        System.out.println("\nThank you for playing!");

    } //end main

} //end class
```

And here is my code which I'm assuming where the problem is coming from:

```
public class RockPaperScissors {


    public String getUserChoice() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your choice:");
        String userInput = sc.nextLine();
        boolean end = true;
        while (end == true){

            //Checks for valid user responses
            if (userInput.equals("rock") || userInput.equals("paper")|| userInput.equals("scissors")){
                end = false;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid response. Please enter rock paper or scissors:");
                userInput = sc.next();
            }
        }

        return userInput;
    }// end getUsechoice

    public String getCPUChoice() {

        String computerChoice = " ";
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        if (randomNum == 1){
            computerChoice = "rock";
        }
        else if (randomNum == 2){
            computerChoice = "paper";
        }
        else if (randomNum == 3){
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        }


        return computerChoice;
    }

    public String pickWinner(String userChoice, String cpuChoice) {
        String result = " ";
        if (getUserChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) { 
            if (getCPUChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
                result = "tie"; 
            }
            else if (getCPUChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
                result = "Computer";
            }
            else if (getCPUChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
                result = "User";
            }       
        }
        else if (getUserChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
            if (getCPUChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
                result = "tie";
            }
            else if (getCPUChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
                result = "User";
            }
            else if (getCPUChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
                result = "Computer";
            }
        }
        else if (getUserChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")){
            if (getCPUChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
                result = "tie";
            }
            else if (getCPUChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
                result = "Computer";
            }
            else if (getCPUChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")){
                result = "User";
            }
        }
        return result;



    }//end pickWinner

}//end rockPaperScissors
```

Here would be a sample session of the program:

> Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!
>
> How many rounds would you like to play? 1 Enter your choice: rock
>   Computer chooses paper Enter your choice: rock Enter your choice: rock
>   Computer wins!
>
> User wins: 0 Computer wins: 1 The computer won!
>
> Thank you for playing!

Here I'm wondering why it continues asking for user input multiple times. Also it runs the other methods as well which is why the computer won despite picking paper vs rock.

Alright added in the final changes to my program and it's working perfectly now:

```
public String pickWinner(String userChoice, String cpuChoice) {
        String result = " ";


        if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) { 
            if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
                result = "tie"; 
            }
            else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
                result = "Computer";
            }
            else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
                result = "User";
            }       
        }
        else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
            if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
                result = "tie";
            }
            else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
                result = "User";
            }
            else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
                result = "Computer";
            }
        }
        else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")){
            if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
                result = "tie";
            }
            else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
                result = "Computer";
            }
            else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")){
                result = "User";
            }
        }
        return result;



    }//end pickWinner
```

The problem seems to be that when I called in getCPUChoice or getUserChoice it would rerun the program and then change the final answers.

Comment: Just a little optimization: Pick the CPU's choice from a `public static final String[] sChoices = {"rock","paper","scissors"}`. Then you can have a random (let's call it pickNr) in {0;2} and get the pick by just `return sChoices[pickNr];` And I'd make the random object a class field, so you don't make a new one in each computerChoice call. Then computerChoice is a 1-liner.

Comment: What bothers me now is that the answer is not very useful for future readers. "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." So it should at least be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calling getUserChoice() in the pickWinner method. It should be the userChoice method parameter you should be checking.

```
public String pickWinner(String userChoice, String cpuChoice) {
String result = " ";
if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) { 
    if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
        result = "tie"; 
    }
    else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
        result = "Computer";
    }
    else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
        result = "User";
    }       
}
else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
    if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
        result = "tie";
    }
    else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
        result = "User";
    }
    else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
        result = "Computer";
    }
}
else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")){
    if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
        result = "tie";
    }
    else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
        result = "Computer";
    }
    else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")){
        result = "User";
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: You've got a sharp eye. )

Comment: Also your for loop although works the standard is to have the variable i start at 0 so this    for (int i = 0; i < numGames; i++)     instead of     for (int i = 1; i <= numGames; i++)

Comment: Ah, yup that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask for user input in each loop and not just once.

```
public class RockPaperScissors {


    public String getUserChoice() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your choice:");
        //not here
        String userInput;
        while (true){
            //this is the right place
            userInput = sc.nextLine();
            //Checks for valid user responses
            if (userInput.equals("rock") || userInput.equals("paper")|| userInput.equals("scissors")){
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid response. Please enter rock paper or scissors:");
            }
        }

        return userInput;
    }// end getUsechoice

//...

}//end rockPaperScissors
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this in your else part

```
 userInput = sc.next();
```

to this

```
userInput = sc.nextLine();
```

So it will go to next line

So the resulting code ll be

```
while (end == true){

    //Checks for valid user responses
    if (userInput.equals("rock") || userInput.equals("paper")|| userInput.equals("scissors")){
        end = false;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid response. Please enter rock paper or scissors:");
        userInput = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: That part of the code seems to work fine at least. It's meant to catch responses that aren't rock, paper, or scissors.